# How to Include associations from json files with sequelize-fixtures?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, sequelize.js, fixtures

**Hello mates,**

I'm pretty new to sequelizejs and just trying to use it. I have problems with the creation of example datasets using **sequelize-fixtures**.

My models are created like so:

**User.js** *(without beforeCreate, beforeUpdate hooks)*

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
        password: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
        active: {type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, default: false}
    });
    return User;
};
```

**Role.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
        title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
        description: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true},
        code: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}
    });
    return Role;
};
```

After importing models into the models object I have created the associations between them:

```
models.User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {through: 'UserRole', constraints: true});
models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'UserRole', constraints: true});
```

And I have loaded the example data from json files used with the structure as the documentation said but the userroles table which was created automagically by sequelize remains empty.

The fixture json file contains the following:

```
[
    {
        "model": "Role",
        "data": {
            "title": "Administrator",
            "description": "Administrator users",
            "code": "RIGHT_ADMIN"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "Role",
        "data": {
            "title": "Manager",
            "description": "Manager users",
            "code": "RIGHT_MANAGEMENT"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "User",
        "keys": [
            "id"
        ],
        "data": {
            "id": 0,
            "email": "admin@app.io",
            "password": "admin",
            "active": true
        },
        "roles":[1,2]
    }
]
```

And the fixture loading will be called after when db synced:
*force: true, left in it for developing reasons only*

```
db.sync({force: true}).then(function () {

    //load fixtures
    SequelizeFixtures.loadFile('fixtures/*.json', models).then(function () {
        console.dir("DEV DATA CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
    });
});
```

**My problem** is that the userroles table which was created by the association of User and Role model always remains empty after running the fixtures.

Answer (score 6):

**FIGURED OUT THE STUFF**

It turnt out that the sequelize fixture document said that the many2many relation values could be defined outside the data of a given model record in the json files.

The solution is to find the relations association key in the $Model.associations object of the Model and use that as a key inside the data object.

**In short:**

this

```
models.User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {through: 'UserRole', constraints: true});
models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'UserRole', constraints: true});
```

is created an association 'Roles' of the User model and a 'Users' of the Role model.

Now according this the json record object should look like this:

```
{
    "model": "User",
    "keys": [
        "id"
    ],
    "data": {
        "id": 0,
        "email": "admin@app.io",
        "password": "admin",
        "active": true,
        "Roles":[1,2]
    }
}
```

[Here is a gist I'have made to show how to use it.](https://gist.github.com/dannystyleart/d491742036d11626f845)

Hope this will help other users of sequelize and sequelize-fixtures